# await messages, get a channel by the given ID

Tags: javascript, async-await, bots, discord, discord.js

So i want that my poll command asks for the channel and the question in a conversation, but i haven't figured out how to get the channel when the user only gives the ID, i have figured out that i have to use .content but i still don't know how to implement it.

My code:

```
run: async(message, client, args) => {

  // Channel where the poll should take palce
  await message.channel.send(`Please provide a channel where the poll should take place or cancel this command with "cancel"!`)
  const response1 = await message.channel.awaitMessages(m => m.author.id === message.author.id, {max: 1});
  const channel = response1.first().mentions.channels.first() || response1.content.guild.channels.cache.get()

  if (!channel) {
    return message.channel.send(`You did not mention or provide the ID of a channel where the poll should take place!`)
  }

  // Channel where the poll should take palce
  await message.channel.send(`Please provide a question for the poll!`)
  const response2 = await message.channel.awaitMessages(m => m.author.id === message.author.id, {max: 1});
  let question = response2.first();

  if (!question) {
    return message.channel.send(`You did not specify your question!`)
  }

  const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`New poll!`)
    .setDescription(`${question}`)
    .setFooter(`${message.author.username} created this poll.`)
    .setColor(`0x0099ff`)
  let msg = await client.channels.cache.get(channel.id).send(Embed)
  await msg.react("")
  await msg.react("")
}
```

And it is this line: `response1.content.guild.channels.cache.get()` that is writte wrong by me but idk what i have to change/where to add the .content so that it works.

Would be nice if someone can help me.

My message event for the args:

```
module.exports = async (client, message) => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
    if (!message.guild) return;
    if (!message.member) message.member = await message.guild.fetchMember(message);
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/g);
    const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    if (cmd.length == 0) return;
    let command = client.commands.get(cmd)
    if (!command) command = client.commands.get(client.aliases.get(cmd));
    if (command) {
        try {
            command.run(message, client, args)
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            message.reply('There was an error trying to execute that command!');
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i went around it with making another constructor means:

const ID = client.channels.cache.get(response1.first().content)
const channel = response1.first().mentions.channels.first() || ID

It works fine now

Answer (score 2):

You need the content to grab the id, but I assume that's already handled by the code that generates the `args` parameter.
To get the guild you can use `Message.guild`, and then just `Guild.channels.cache.get()`

That means that your code would look like this:

```js
const channel = response1.first().mentions.channels.first() 
  || response1.first().guild.channels.cache.get(args[0]) // Assuming args[0] is your id
```

Comment: thanks but "channels" is undefined like that, that is what the error says, and yeah the content is handled by the args, i forgot that

Comment: response1.first().guild.channels.cache.get()     that was recommended by someone but it then goes to the if(!channel)

Comment: I've updated my answer (I forgot to add `.first()` after `response1`. About your problem: please see that its not just .`get()`, but you need to pass in the id (`.get(args[0]`)

Comment: i now have it ecactly like your comment (with your edit) but it still doesn't accepts the Id (it is a real channel Id, i made sure) and goes straight to the if (!channel), really annoys me...

Comment: You should try doing some debugging to make sure that the arguments are picked up correctly...
Try using `console.log` to see if `response1`, `args[0]` and the two statements you use for `channel` are correct.

Comment: so when i log response1 it logs/shows all the methods but when i log channel then it logs /shows "undefined" but what is undefined?

Comment: And what about `args[0]`?

Comment: also undefined, so i guess i have to look into my message event, that i will add to this question

Comment: Yeah, try using `console.log` there too to see where exactly is the problem, since it's certainly in that part of the code. Try logging the `args` array and, if the ID is present in just after the definition, try to see where it disappears

Comment: whyever the the args are undefined the message.content is undefined idk anymore/what have i done wrong ... frustrating

Comment: i think i will jus only go with the mention

Comment: `message.content` should **NEVER** be undefined, this shows that you have a problem in your command handler. I know this can be frustrating, but if you don't try to solve this your bot will continue to have this problem, and it's not a little one. This however is beyond the topic of this question, so I advise you look carefully at that and open other questions if needed. If, after you fixed this issue, you still need to do this command, you can look at my answer, which should be valid